# Flask Sessions not working with blueprints

Tags: python, flask, flask-session

I am using flask sessions, i recently changed my code structure to be blueprint based, it has broken sessions. Whevenver i try to access sessions inside a blueprint, it is giving me

```
RuntimeError: The session is unavailable because no secret key was set.  Set the secret_key on the application to something unique and secret.
```

This is the code from the main application:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(authModule, url_prefix='/auth', cookie_path='/')
app.secret_key = environ.get('secret_key')
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_PATH'] = '/'
```

Can anybody tell me what is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue is related to the Flask session's secret key not being set properly. Here are some possible reasons why this error might occur:

The secret_key variable is not being set correctly, or is not being set at all.
The app.secret_key variable is being overwritten or changed after it is initially set.
The Flask application is not being run in a secure environment, such as in development mode with the DEBUG flag set to True.
The Flask application is running on a different server or port, causing the session cookie to be invalid or inaccessible.
To troubleshoot the issue, you can try the following:

Double-check that the secret_key variable is being set correctly, and is not being overwritten or changed elsewhere in your code.
Ensure that the app.secret_key variable is being set before any other code that uses the session object.
Verify that the Flask application is being run in a secure environment, such as by setting the SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE and SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY variables to True.
Check that the Flask application is running on the correct server and port, and that the session cookie is being sent and received correctly.

Comment: thanks for trying to help, but it is not working

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).